# Vector spaces whose elements are functions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to understand what a vector of functions is, from trying to understand how to solve linear homogeneous differential equations.

It seems that functions can be manipulated as vectors as long as they are not interpreted as having real values.
Suppose the solution space of a linear homogeneous diff equation is spanned by $\cos(x)$, $\sin(x)$, then the solution is $a \sin(x) + b \cos(x)$, and it's a vector.

But, if $y$ is a vector $y = a \sin(x) + b \cos(x)$, then how is it that for any value of $x$, $y$ is always a scalar value?

If $x$ is a set of values rather than a symbol then how can $y$ remain a vector if, for each element of $x$, $y$ is scalar?

Comment: I better give up this wild goose chase. But, I have two questions; 1. how do I phrase or categorize the conditions for which f is a vector in the solution space, in terms of x? Since I can say that f(x) is a vector in R1 for any, all, and some x. I find it hard to accept that f could be a vector in the solution space as long as it is unrelated to x. (unless I say that f.i + x.j forms some other vector :) ). 2. Is there a way to transform the solution space into something that can describe the function along with it's values?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an analogy that might help:

I suppose that the "vector" that you normally think of is a list of coordinates.  For example, $(-1,-2,-3,-4)$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^4$.

Note, however, that we could also represent this list of numbers as a function.  In particular, if we define $f:\{1,2,3,4\} \to \Bbb R$ by
$$
f(1) = -1\\
f(2) = -2\\
f(3) = -3\\
f(4) = -4
$$
then it makes sense to think of $f$ as the same vector.  In fact, we could also have written this "vector", then, as $f(x) = -x$.  Plugging in any valid value of $x$ (in this case, any integer from $1$ to $4$), we get one of the coordinates of $f$, our vector.

In a similar vein, the function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = \cos(x)$ can be thought of as a vector that has a "coordinate" at every $x \in \Bbb R$.

---

In the end of the day, the idea that a vector should be defined strictly by its coordinates is flawed.  Mathematically speaking, a vector is anything that can be added to like things and multiplied by numbers in such a way that the expected rules of arithmetic do hold (try looking up the "vector-space axioms").

The notion of coordinates does, however, often provide helpful intuition.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23199/discussion-on-answer-by-omnomnomnom-linear-transform-of-functions).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question entirely (in particular "If x is a set of values rather than a symbol then how can y remain a vector if for each element of x, y is scalar?"), but perhaps this will help:

The ODE
$$y''(x) + y(x) = 0$$
is homogeneous and linear, and so its space of solutions is a vector space $\Bbb V$, and its constituent vectors are functions (under usual addition and scalar multiplication of functions). Since $$x \mapsto \sin x \qquad \text{and} \qquad x \mapsto \cos x$$ are linearly independent (there are $a, b$ not both zero such that $a \sin x + b \cos x = 0$, where both sides denote functions) and the ODE has order $2$, those functions together form a basis of $\Bbb V$.

Just as with any vector space and any basis, we can write any element of the vector space as a unique linear combination of elements of the basis, that is, we can write
$${\Bbb V} = \{ x \mapsto a \sin x + b \cos x : a, b \in {\Bbb R}\} ,$$
and as always (at least when the vector space is finite-dimensional) we can thus specify any element of the space as a column vector in ${\Bbb R}^2$ with entries the coefficients in the linear combination. With respect to our basis, the element
$$x \mapsto a \sin x + b \cos x$$
has representation
$$\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix}.$$
As always, we use the entries of the column vector as coordinates on our underlying vector space $\Bbb V$.

All of what we've said so far is independent of taking functions in $\mathbb{V}$ and evaluating them at particular values $x_0$, but there's nothing wrong with doing so. In fact, for any $x_0 \in {\Bbb R}$ we get an *evaluation map*
$$\phi_{x_0}: {\Bbb V} \to {\Bbb R}$$
given simply by
$$\phi_{x_0}(f) := f(x_0).$$
For a general vector $f : x \mapsto a \sin x + b \cos x$, we have
$$\phi_{x_0}(f) = a \sin x_0 + b \cos x_0 = \begin{pmatrix}\sin x_0 & \cos x_0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix},$$
and so $\phi_{x_0}$ is actually a *linear* map and has matrix representation
$$\begin{pmatrix}\sin x_0 & \cos x_0\end{pmatrix}$$
w.r.t. the basis dual to $(\sin x, \cos x)$. In short, because the elements $f \in \Bbb V$ are functions, we can evaluate them, but the values $f(x_0)$ are elements of an altogether separate vector space.

To be clear, it's fine that we usually think of elements of $\Bbb R$ as vectors, by the way, $\Bbb R$ is certainly a vector space---indeed, consulting the vector space axioms show that every field is a vector space over itself.

Comment: In a vector space a function is equivalent to a geometric point, but each function evaluates to some pattern on R. If a function unevaluated is a point, then can R (unevaluated is the right term?) be a point?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "each function evaluates to some pattern on $R$". What pattern? I also don't know what "can $R$ be a point?" means. Is $R$ here the real numbers?

Comment: The pattern as in a set of elements. I mean R as the set of real numbers as an evaluation of the function the function like f(x) = x, does that make sense?

Comment: No, I don't think I understand. By the "set of elements" do you mean the domain of $f$? Or its image? Or something else?

Comment: I don't know. But the functions evaluate to scalars or points of R^1

Comment: Hmm ... I don't really know what I'm asking, but if you can consider R^1 to be the image of a function the f -> R, f is a point in a vector space ?

Comment: The elements of our particular vector space $\mathbb{V}$ are functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, functions with *codomain* $\mathbb{R}$ (the image of a given $f$ in this case turns out to be a little more complicated, but that's not important for your question, I think).